# DBMS Job with function

Tags: oracle11g, dbms-job

I have this DBMS Job that run at the end of day to clean the data and I have this function available CLEAN_SNAPSHOT_DATA_F(7).

I try running this script below.

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'select OPTIEXEC_ADMIN.CLEAN_SNAPSHOT_DATA_F(7) from dual',
                      next_date => to_date('11-06-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                      interval => 'SYSDATE + 24/24');
  commit;
end;
```

But the error return ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Can you advice what the issue about the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE
jb_av NUMBER;
BEGIN
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => jb_av, 
                      what => 'DECLARE lv_var VARCHAR2(32676); BEGIN select OPTIEXEC_ADMIN.CLEAN_SNAPSHOT_DATA_F(7) INTO lv_var from dual;END;', 
                      next_date => to_date('11-06-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 
                      interval => 'SYSDATE + 24/24');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. May I know what is the 1 represent?

Comment: just a dummy value for valid select query.

Comment: sorry it said, var statement is invalid statement then Begin onward is still the same error.

Comment: replace var with DECLARE